# Как изменить цвет иконок в toolbar?

Tags: java, android

У меня есть тулбар к которому я добавил список с меню.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<!--Action buttons -->
<item
    android:id="@+id/toolbar_attach"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_action_attachment_2"
    android:orderInCategory="0"
    android:title="@string/attach"
    app:showAsAction="always"
    />

<item
    android:id="@+id/toolbar_record"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_action_mic"
    android:orderInCategory="1"
    android:title="@string/record"
    app:showAsAction="always" />

<!--Popup menu-->

<item
    android:id="@+id/toolbar_save"
    android:orderInCategory="0"
    android:title="@string/save"
    app:showAsAction="never" />

<item
    android:id="@+id/toolbar_cancel"
    android:orderInCategory="1"
    android:title="@string/cancel"
    app:showAsAction="never" />
<item
    android:id="@+id/toolbar_delete"
    android:orderInCategory="2"
    android:title="@string/delete"
    app:showAsAction="never" />
```

Проблема в том, что цвет тулбара темный и иконки на нём теряются (помечены showAsAction). Поэтому хочу поменять их цвет, например на белый.

[image: картинка]

Искал варианты, попробовал android:iconTint="желаемый_цвет", но данное решение подходит для api 26+. 
Подскажите решение.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Вы можете сделать это программно [так](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31953613/3212712):

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);

    for(int i = 0; i < menu.size(); i++){
        Drawable drawable = menu.getItem(i).getIcon();
        if(drawable != null) {
            drawable.mutate();
            drawable.setColorFilter(getResources().getColor(R.color.textColorPrimary), PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_ATOP);
        }
    }

    return true;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Для более ранних версий API, вы можете изменить **цвет самих иконок**. В папке `drawable`, находите нужную иконку, открываете и вместо черного (по умолчанию) указываете нужный цвет.

```
<path
    android:fillColor="@color/blue"
    android:pathData="..."/>
```

Так же стоит заметить, что изменить цвет можно только для **векторных** иконок. Если вы по каким то причинам используете **растр**, то цвет таких иконок можно изменить только в графическом редакторе.

Comment: Хорошее решение, но в моем случае иконки не векторные, а растровые. Спасибо за ответ.

Comment: Так для растровых вы и сможете поменять цвет. Используйте **Vector Asset** для добавления векторных иконок. Судя по скрину они стандартные.

Comment: @ЕвгенийВасильев, вы уверены что ваши иконки растровые. Судя по коду `@drawable/ic_action_mic` это похоже на вектор.

Comment: Если я не ошибаюсь, то формат .png не предназначен для векторных изображений, а мои иконки имеют именно этот формат.

Comment: @ЕвгенийВасильев, вы правы, png это не вектор. Просто странно, что они лежат в папке drawable. Поправил ответ.